# Break lines in cell after creating drop-down list with few arguments

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, calc

I use libre office calc.
I have simple calc sheet with some customers data:

[sheet with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LMP5.png)

Now i want create drop-down list, where i will choose detailed customer data to have his basic data, only name, surname and address.

I used formula like this in data -> validity -> cell range:

```
Name&" "&Surname&" "&Address
```

It works, but it not looks nice. Text is long and it depends on length of cell.
I would like to have it in this way:

```
<First name> <Last Name>

<Address>
```

Is that possible to do in this way?
If yes, is it also possibility to divide address automatically into two lines after comma or in place i will choose?

Comment: LibreOffice Base forms are more powerful for working with related data. You may want to try it and see if it meets your needs. However, it can be more difficult to learn than Calc, so you will need to decide whether a simple spreadsheet is good enough.