# Depended Drop-down list with this same names in cells sometimes

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, calc

i have easy libre office calc sheet:
[my_sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou0M9.png)

I have two columns, country and name. I want to create a depended drop-down list. First list will have country name, and second it will have choosen name from this country.

But when i do it, i have for example 'England' name few times, not only once.

I used this formula in -> data -> validity -> cell range:

```
$Sheet4.$A$2:$A$7
```

I don't know how to change it and how to give possibility to choose every name from that country then.

Comment: This should be straightforward to do in LibreOffice Base, which I suggested for your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60019778/break-lines-in-cell-after-creating-drop-down-list-with-few-arguments. A dependent list can also be done in Calc: - https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/67913/cell-dependent-drop-down/
- https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/56176/how-to-make-a-drop-down-list-dependent-on-another/

Comment: It may help to give a specific example of the results you want. Please put the example in text in the question, which is easier to work with than a link to an image.